# Can't retrieve minimized LibreOffice Writer

Tags: launcher, libreoffice

When I minimize an open document I am working on in LibreOffice Writer, it disappears into the launcher panel. It does not show any little white arrow beside the LibreOffice writer icon. When I click it, it opens up a new document. I cannot get my original document back unless I do <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Does anyone have a fix, or is this a new bug? Running 12.04 LTS.

Comment: I have recently experienced that with LibreOffice **3.5.4.2**.  I don't often minimize **Writer** windows, and have more often experienced this issue with **Calc**.  But only in the last 3-4 weeks.

Comment: I have experienced unity losing minimised windows, and even just moving them around, particularly when I switch workspaces a lot and when windows are child windows of another (such as pop-up dialogs).  Seems to be a untity bug and I have been surprised that there haven't been more mentions of it  around yet.

Comment: After a LOT of searching, I found the appropriate bug for this issue here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1026426  Please go and vote for it.

Comment: I have the same problem. Calc is on my linux mint panel so I right click on calc in the panel. It then shows a black box with a white vertical bar - presumably the actual s/s). I select maximize and it returns the maximized sheet. It's a bug for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if its going to work in the future but maybe try this:

```
unity --replace & disown
```

At the moment it fixed the problem with disappearing LibreOffice Writer windows after minimizing them.

Comment: It works, but it's more an hack than a solution. It seems like a "soft" restart of X. Thanks anyway, it helped me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're not looking at the Icon you used to launch the program but down further on the Unity dock. It sounds to me as if you keep launching the program, and creating new documents, when it is launched.

[image: Example]

Comment: I checked that out as well, there is no icon below

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to preview all windows and then select the LibreOffice window from that preview rather than from the dock icon.

Comment: This works but the OP already mentioned the use of super+w.